# Selective SSL with .htaccess force http:// or https://

Tags: performance, apache, http, .htaccess, ssl

I am trying to be more selective in which pages/requests are using `SSL` for performance reasons. I would like to use `htaccess` to redirect to `https://` for only the required pages and redirect back to `http://` for everything else. This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On

# force https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(abc|xyz)(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/$2 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https(.*)/(abc|xyz)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/(abc|xyz)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ initialize.php [QSA,L]
```

The secure requests are meant to be `abc` or `xyz`. The problem is that if `http:// example.com/abc` is requested it is redirecting to `http://example.com/initialize.php`. A non-secure page works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a several year old question I am quite sure it's solved already, but for people that might run into this I think something like this could work. It's a bit hard to know what `abc` and `xyz` is above, but I will assume they are part of the `URI` path.

```
# Forward some URI's to HTTPS.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond $1 (abc|xyz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,S=1,L]

# Forward rest of the request to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond $1 !(abc|xyz) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ initialize.php [QSA,L]
```

Also the tips to troubleshoot this would be to enable [mod_rewrite logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).